# Dynamic Linked Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to construct a dynamic query to for a linked server (and if so how)?

For example:

```
@linkedServer varchar(50)
@var1 varchar(10)
@var2 varchar(10)

select * 
  from openquery(@linkedServer, 
                 'select c1,c2 
                    from t1 
                   where p1 = @var1 
                     and p2= @var2')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

example

```
exec ('select * from openquery(' + @linkedServer + 
', ''select c1,c2 from t1 where p1 = '' + @var1 + ''and p2= '' + @var2 + ''')
```

make sure to read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) to protect against SQL injection

Comment: Isn't the closing bracket for `openquery()` missing?

Comment: 12 years and 8 months later, I have a question. How do I create a view out of this query? I have a similar exec('select statement) at LinkedServer which works fine. Now I want to create a View which I will then use with Power BI. When I write the standard  Create View Viewname AS exec('select statement) at LinkedServer.. I get an error because create view is expecting a select statement after AS... Kindly assist

Answer (score 2):

see [EXEC() at Linked Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#EXECatlinked) section of [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

from that article:

> A special feature added in SQL 2005 is
>   that you can use EXEC() to run
>   pass-through queries on a linked
>   server. This could be another instance
>   of SQL Server, but it could also be an
>   Oracle server, an Access database,
>   Active directory or whatever. The SQL
>   could be a single query or a sequence
>   of statements, and could it be
>   composed dynamically or be entirely
>   static. The syntax is simple, as seen
>   by this example:
>
> EXEC('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @db +
>   '.dbo.sysobjects') AT SQL2K
>
> SQL2K is here a linked server that has
>   been defined with sp_addlinkedserver.

Comment: doesn't work with a dynamically named linked server, this doesn't work...EXEC('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.sysobjects') AT @linkedServer

Comment: @SQLMenace, this will work `EXEC ('EXEC(''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @db + '.dbo.sysobjects'') AT '+@linkedServer)`